# Как связать тройку значений?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно связать три поля:

```
int numParametr
string nameColToSave
string nameTableDB
```

К примеру это должно выглядеть так `(905, "Colum", "Table")` и потом каждое значение должно быть использовано, по "ключу" (905) подставляем значения таблицы и столбца.

Хотел использовать `Dictionary <int, Dictionary <string, string>>` но ужасно не удобно добавлять, как можно сделать по другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .NET 4-й версии для совместимости с функциональными языками добавлен тип *кортеж* (tuple).

Вы можете воспользоваться вариантом `Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, string>>`.

Кроме того, всегда можно завести класс или структуру с именоваными полями:

```
public class UpdateUnit
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Такой код гораздо легче читать и изменять, не смотря на то, что появился один «как бы лишний» класс.

Comment: Благодарю, кортежи это то что нужно. Класс я рассматривал как вариант, но попробую кортежи